# No able to use rosserial_arduino

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys, I built ROS indigo on my pi 2 and tried to use the rosserial_arduino (after making my workspace having rosserial metapackage with catkin_make install). The problem is that whenever i try to initialize serial communication with an arduino with `rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0`,it just says `: No such file or directory`. I checked my ports with `ls /dev` and my arduino is on ttyACM0. Please help me out.

EDIT

This problem was solved by rebuilding my workspace with `catkin_make install` but new errors have crept up again :

This is the error now on executing `rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_python/nodes/serial_node.py", line 39, in <module>
from rosserial_python import SerialClient, RosSerialServer
File "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosserial_python/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
exec(__fh.read())
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_python/src/rosserial_python/SerialClient.py", line 51, in <module>
import diagnostic_msgs.msg
ImportError: No module named diagnostic_msgs.msg
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229719/no-able-to-use-rosserial_arduino/) by [nishthapa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25875/nishthapa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2016-03-21

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-22**:
It looks like part of the error message is missing; can you edit your question to include the command you're running and the full error message?

**Comment by [nishthapa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25875/nishthapa/) on 2016-03-23**:
No. I copy pasted the error message. That's all it says. Nothing more. I checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys i solved it. All i had to do was rebuild my workspace with `catkin_make install` and install the `diagnostic_msgs` package into a source built ROS distribution. Thank you all for your help.

---

Originally posted by [nishthapa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25875/nishthapa/) with karma: 47 on 2016-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a couple of possible error scenarios here: either it can't open your serial port, or you don't have a good version of python installed (or something else). Since it still looks like you haven't pasted the complete output from the program, it's hard to tell exactly what is wrong.

If I run rosserial_python and my serial port doesn't exist, I get this message:

```
$ rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1458751932.062218] ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [WallTime: 1458751932.064663] Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 57600 baud
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1458751932.065596] Error opening serial: could not open port /dev/ttyACM0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyACM0'
```

If I run rosserial_python and my version of python is broken, I get this message:

```
$ rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0
/usr/bin/env: python: No such file or directory
```

**UPDATE**:

It now looks like you're missing the common_msgs package (which includes diagnostic_msgs). This seems like a step backwards.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nishthapa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25875/nishthapa/) on 2016-03-29**:
Yes but currently, I dont need the common_msgs but only diagnostic_msgs so I only installed diagnostic_msgs.